# Massive Mail cannot open

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

Here’s the problem my friend dragged and dropped 5000 emails in to another email accidently he only wanted to move them. Consequently there is 1 single email with 5,000 attachments.

The single email file is 750MB he cannot open the email outlook crashes. He cannot copy the email system hangs.

This is on exchange server and the on client side outlook is 2010.

The OST is intact and I have a copy, Outlook works fine until you go anywhere near the file, preview or try to open.

Has anyone any thoughts on how to recover these emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully used [this tutorial](http://outlook-center.com/Deleting-a-message-stuck-in-Outbox-using-MFCMAPI/49/) to remove a really large message that was stuck in the outbox.  Same kind of issues as you're describing.

The software, [Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Editor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2953), used in the tutorial basically allows you get in and remove the message without Outlook being open.

Disclosure:  I used this on a local install (no exchange involved).

Comment: I will give it a try have you moved email rather than delete?

Comment: I just deleted when I did it.  The software looks quite detailed though.  It may be possible to move rather than delete.